# Не могу получить ответ от Okex по websoket api python

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

На нескольких биржах работает, здесь же приходит ответ в другом формате. Вот код:

```
import json
import requests
import time
import csv
import websocket

def on_message(ws, message):
    msg = json.loads(message)
    print(msg)
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    ws.send('{"op": "subscribe", "args":"spot/ticker:ETH-USDT}')
    print("### connected ###")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://real.okex.com:8443/ws/v3",
                                      on_message = on_message,
                                      on_error = on_error,
                                      on_close = on_close)
    ws = websocket.create_connection("wss://real.okex.com:8443/ws/v3")
    ws.send('{"op": "subscribe", "args":["futures/ticker:ETH-USD-190927"]}')
    while True:
        print(ws.recv())
```

Ответ приходит такого формата:
b'\xabVJ-K\xcd+Q\xb2RJ-*\xca/R\xd2Q\xcaM-.NLO\x05\x8a8g$\xe6\xe5\xa5\xe6(\xa4\x95\x96\x94\x16\xa5\x16\xeb\x97d&g\xa7\x16Y\xb9\x86x\xe8\x86\x06\xbb\xe8\x1aZ\x1aX\x1a\x99+\xa4\xe4\xa7\x16\xe7\xa9\x97(\xa4Vd\x16\x97\x00\xf5\x83\xcdq\xceO\x01\x9a`l``bP\x0b\x00'
А должен быть ответ такого типа:

```
{"event":"subscribe","channel":"spot/ticker:ETH-USDT"}

 {"event":"subscribe","channel":"spot/candle60s:ETH-USDT"}

 {"table":"spot/ticker","data":[{"instrument_id":"ETH-USDT","last":"8.8","best_bid":"3","best_ask":"8.1","open_24h":"5.1","high_24h":"8.8","low_24h":"3","base_volume_24h":"13.77340909",
 "quote_volume_24h":"78.49886361","timestamp":"2018-12-20T03:13:41.664Z"}]}

 {"table":"spot/candle60s","data":[{"candle":["2018-12-20T06:18:00.000Z","8.8","8.8","8.8","8.8","0"],"instrument_id":"ETH-USDT"}]}
```

Comment: Узнать у них в каком формате они возвращают данные

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его галочкой как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [их API](https://github.com/okex/V3-Open-API-SDK/blob/master/okex-python-sdk-api/websocket_example.py) вы в ответе получили сжатые данные. Во всяком случае функция `inflate()` из их примера вашу "строку" расшифровывает:

```
import zlib

def inflate(data):
    decompress = zlib.decompressobj(-zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    inflated = decompress.decompress(data)
    inflated += decompress.flush()
    return inflated

data_compressed_str = '\xabVJ-K\xcd+Q\xb2RJ-*\xca/R\xd2Q\xcaM-.NLO\x05\x8a8g$\xe6\xe5\xa5\xe6(\xa4\x95\x96\x94\x16\xa5\x16\xeb\x97d&g\xa7\x16Y\xb9\x86x\xe8\x86\x06\xbb\xe8\x1aZ\x1aX\x1a\x99+\xa4\xe4\xa7\x16\xe7\xa9\x97(\xa4Vd\x16\x97\x00\xf5\x83\xcdq\xceO\x01\x9a`l``bP\x0b\x00'
data_compressed_bytes = data_compressed_str.encode('latin1')
data_bytes = inflate(data_compressed_bytes)
data_str = data_bytes.decode('utf-8')
print(data_str)
```

На выходе получается:

```
{"event":"error","message":"Channel futures/ticker:ETH-USD-190927 doesn\'t exist","errorCode":30040}
```

Comment: Супер! А как теперь это можно совместить в один код, чтобы на выходе получались данные не в сжатом виде?

Comment: Очевидно добавить вызов этой функции в случае получения в ответе сжатых данных. ;) Или в случае общения именно с данным сайтом.

Comment: Немного не получается. Добавляю такой код: def inflate(data):
    decompress = zlib.decompressobj(-zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    inflated = decompress.decompress(data)
    inflated += decompress.flush()
    return inflated Выдает такое сообщение:TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Ну так превратите вашу строку в байты - `data_bytes = bytes(data_str, 'latin1')`.

Comment: @BitcoinEarn Изменил ответ. Расписал там как преобразовать строку в байты и байты в строку (во избежании последующих вопросов).

Comment: Все сделал, как вы посоветовали. Выдает ошибку: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode' Ошибка выдается скорее всего из-за первого символа: b. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно превратить строку в байты, исключив этот символ или наборот, вместе с ним.

Comment: Не, ну я всё же расписал. Не вызывайте `encode` для `bytes`.Оно для преобразования строки в байты. Если оно уже байты, то зачем вы вызываете?(хотя сообщением ранее вы утверждали, что там строка - вы уж определитесь как-нибудь) Можно вызвать `decode` для преобразования байт в строку и `encode` чтобы преобразовать обратно. И вы получите те же самые данные, что в начале. Только зачем этот сизифов труд?